# Can't run command create wrapper federation

Tags: db2, wrapper, federation, biginsights

I'm trying to setup BigInsights Federation to Netezza following [this guideline](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ba-federation-biginsights/index.html).

But when I execute command create wrapper, I got an error:

> [C2-BIGDATA-BIGINS-MGTNODE.VMS2.COM.VN][bigsql] 1> create wrapper nz library 'libdb2rcodbc.so' OPTIONS(MODULE '/opt/ibm/SDAP71/lib/libodbc.so');
>   SQL Exception(s) Encountered:
>   [State: 58004][Code: 15]: BIGSQL-GEN-0010 Found an internal error: 'Failed to execute query 'create wrapper nz library 'libdb2rcodbc.so' OPTIONS(MODULE '/opt/ibm/SDAP71/lib/libodbc.so')': line 1:8: unexpected token: wrapper'.

Do you know where is an error come from?
How can I check federation server is enable?

Comment: Try executing the statements using the command line processor, as shown in the tutorial: `db2 "create wrapper ..."`

Comment: I use db2 command and connect to bigsql database, then I execute commend: "create wrapper nz" and error message is:
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0204N  "NZ" is an undefined name.  SQLSTATE=42704